# Implementing an IO Pipeline in JEE ( Wildfly 11.0)

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am porting some code from a standalone application to have a web based front end. We are using wildfly 11.0 as the container. The code made heavy use of threads and I am not sure how to implement that in JEE. On secton in partiular uses piped streams with one process writing into it and another reading out of it. Both processes do file IO and may block. The section of code is responsible for zipping up a large directory tree and chunking the zip file into multiple separate files. This is a long running process as the directories to be zipped are in the gigabyte range. How can I manage forking off two threads connected by a piped input stream in JEE, or is there a best practice for accomplishing the same result.

Here is an example of the code in question

```
ExecutorService Executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
File directoryToZip = new File(dirToZipName);
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
pos.connect(pis);
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
// get all files into a list
getAllFiles(directoryToZip, fileList); 
Callable<Void> producer = () -> writeZipFile(pos, directoryToZip,fileList);
Callable<FileMetaData> consumer = () ->    FileSplitter.splitFile(pis,directoryToZip.getName(), new File(outputDir), 1024);
Future<FileMetaData> future = Executor.submit(consumer);
Executor.submit(producer);
future.get();
Executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, application will be implemented so that only exactly one pipeline will exist at anytime. Additional requests will be refused until a running process is complete.

Comment: Have you looked at the `ManagedExecutorService` in Java EE 7? It can just injected into managed resources. http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/javaee_7_injecting_a_managedexecutorservice